# Implementing basic working owl.carousel.js in odoo 14

Tags: javascript, web, odoo

I'am migrating a template from odoo 12 to Odoo 14 and using "owl.carousel" and other JS, and none of them work. I got these errors when implementing owl.carousel :
[image]

```
odoo.define('website_theme.frontend_layout', function (require) {
'use strict';
    $('.class1').owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        responsive:{
            0:{ items:1
            },
            1000:{ items:2
            },
            2000:{
                items:3}
        }
    })
    $('.class2').vegasMenu();
});




<div class="d-none d-xl-block header-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-7">
                            <div class="class1 owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                <div class="item">
                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    
                                </div>....
```

Any help please? How can I solve it ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: How did you add the js assets? Owl Carousel v2.3.4 is working fine on Odoo14. You need to check why Odoo Rises `TypeError: a is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma on the navigation line

Comment: Missed a semi colon before $(class2) as well